# How to convert a resource image to IImage in .Net Maui?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a resource image in .Net Maui Project.

```
ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile("somefile.jpg");
```

I need to convert it to `IImage`.

For an image loaded from internet, I do

```
    HttpWebRequest wreq;
    HttpWebResponse wresp;
    Stream mystream;
            
    string url = "https://someurl/somefile.jpg";

    wreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    wreq.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

    wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wreq.GetResponse();
    mystream = wresp.GetResponseStream();

    IImage image = PlatformImage.FromStream(mystream);
```

Can I do that when the image is embedded as project resource?

Answer (score 1):

this is covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/images)

```
IImage image;
Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("GraphicsViewDemos.Resources.Images.dotnet_bot.png"))
{
#if IOS || ANDROID || MACCATALYST
    // PlatformImage isn't currently supported on Windows.
    image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
#elif WINDOWS
    image = new W2DImageLoadingService().FromStream(stream);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jason for your answer. I'm strugling with GetManifestResourceStream. I did GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName.Resources.Images.dotnet_bot.png") but the result is null. Do you have any idea please ?

Comment: in the MAUI template `dotnet_bot` is a MauiAsset, not an embedded resource